# Connecting to MongoDB via a hotspot is not working

Tags: mongodb, dns

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB Atlas cluster via a phone hotspot. My IP is in the Access List and I'm able to connect on a normal internet connection at home or in the office, but it doesn't work when I'm on a phone hotspot. The connection just times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cell carriers automatically connect you to a DNS server that doesn't support SRV records. That means using the `mongodb+srv` protocol while running on a hotspot from your phone using one of these carriers will fail. In my experience it causes the connection to timeout.

This can be solved 2 ways:

1. Use an alternative DNS such as Google's at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`
2. Use the standard `mongodb://` protocol in your connection string. This connection string will be longer and more verbose.

If you go with option 1, **Double check these IPs before using them. They probably will never change, but you'd never want to use untrusted DNS server so better to double check**.

Also note that in Windows 11, I had to change my DNS and then restart the machine. I read you could run `ipconfig /flushdns` but that had no effect for me.